# Pandas pipeline with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas pipeline and would like to use either `count` or `mean` function based on a boolean variable.

I came out with the following solution:

```
import pandas as pd # version 1.0.4

my_boolean = False
df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')

pipeline = (df.groupby('species')['sepal_length']
            # .count() or .mean() based on value of my_boolean variable
              .pipe(pd.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean if my_boolean 
                        else pd.core.groupby.GroupBy.size)
            )
```

I had to change `pd.core.groupby.GroupBy.count` by `pd.core.groupby.GroupBy.size` as I encoutered a `NotImplementedError` for `count` function.

Is there a better way to handle conditions within pipelines?

Thanks

Comment: @jezrael it looks like they want to implement conditional logic for different columns

Comment: 1.0.4. Have you tested the count function?

Comment: yop, also raise error.

Comment: Is `my_boolean` meant to be scalar? Or do you intend to use it to select columns?

Comment: Just select a function, thanks for pointing out methodcaller, didn't know that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to `lambda` and it seems to work fine:

```
my_boolean = False
df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')

pipeline = (df.groupby('species')['sepal_length']
            # .count() or .mean() based on value of my_boolean variable
              .pipe(lambda g: g.mean() if my_boolean 
                        else g.count())
            )
```

Comment: Another option is to use `methodcaller('mean') if my_boolean else methodcaller('count')` - `from operator import methodcaller`

Answer (score 2):

You can also monkey patch a specific function that will execute the `pipe` only if a condition is met.

```py
import time

import pandas as pd
from pandas.core import common as com

def pipeif(self, func: 'Callable[..., T] | tuple[Callable[..., T], str]',
    *args,
    cond:'bool'=True,
    **kwargs,    
        ):
    if cond:
        return com.pipe(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return self

pd.DataFrame.pipeif = pipeif
```

A small example with a function that print current time and is executed only twice (as the second pipeif has a `False` cond argument).

[image]